# DatePicker wrapper types with luxon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, luxon

By generating DatePicker with luxon like this

```
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
import type { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import luxonGenerateConfig from 'rc-picker/lib/generate/luxon';

const LuxonDatePicker = DatePicker.generatePicker<DateTime>(
  luxonGenerateConfig,
);
```

i can use whatever i want on

the problem is i want to wrap this with another component to have label and error message etc for reusability.

```
interface CustomProps {
  label?: string;
  errorMessage?: string;
  hasError?: boolean;
}

export type DatePickerProps = CustomProps &
  React.ComponentProps<typeof LuxonDatePicker>;

const DatePicker: React.FC<DatePickerProps> = ({
  label,
  errorMessage,
  hasError,
  ...rest
}) => {
```

now rest.onChange's type is

```
(property) onChange?: ((date: unknown, dateString: string | string[]) => void) | undefined
```

while

```
<LuxonDatePicker
onChange
```

is

```
(property) onChange?: ((date: DateTime<boolean>, dateString: string | string[]) => void) | undefined
```

i can't find a way to keep the working types of my Component

Also is there a way i can implement       with props?

Comment: What the error did you get?

Comment: No errors just wrong type values.

Comment: I can't reproduce, `<LuxonDatePicker {...rest} />` works fine.

Comment: onChange types are mismatched.

<LuxonDatePicker onChange

and 

<DatePicker onChange is different